# largest permutation group of odd order

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

For general $n$, what is the largest subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ that has odd order?

I have a feeling that it might be the Sylow 3-subgroup...**ADDED:** but it isn't, as Mark Bennet points out in a comment.  If I calculate right, it isn't true for large $n$ either, as $\mathrm{Syl_3}(S_{n-5}) \times C_5$ beats $\mathrm{Syl_3}(S_n)$ when $n=9k+5$ for integer $k$.  But is it the biggest?

Comment: For $S_5$ you have a subgroup of order $5$, for $S_8$ you have a subgroup of order $15$ generated by a $5$-cycle and a disjoint $3$-cycle.

Comment: Observe that such a subgroup $H$ must lie in $A_n$ (since index$[HA_n:A_n]$ divides 2). So it depends on how you can partition $n$ in *odd* numbers, maximizing their l.c.m..

Comment: @NickyHekster: This construction yields a **cyclic** subgroup of $A_n$ of maximal size (w.r.t. being of odd order). Are you sure there aren't any larger ones that aren't cyclic (maybe not even abelian)?