# Permutation with largest odd order

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, optimization, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ denotes symmetric group of $n$ symbols. What is the maximal odd order of permutation in $S_n$?

In other words, what is the value of $\max\{\text{ord }\sigma : \sigma\in S_n, \text{ord }\sigma \text{is odd} \} $ where $\text{ord }\sigma$ denotes smallest positive integer $m$ which satisfies $\sigma ^m = \text{id}$ ?

Comment: [This entry in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A051593) is _possibly_ the sequence you're looking for, but an even-order permutation needs not be an odd permutation, so I'm not entirely certain that they are the same. At any rate, it's the only OEIS entry that has the correct first few terms.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787581/largest-permutation-group-of-odd-order) might be of interest.

Comment: @Arthur I see that the sequence is similar since odd-order permutations are even permutations, but after some observations, I figured out when $n \ge 18$, most sequence is even. Why do you think most numbers in the sequence are even?

Comment: @David Actually, I was thinking of a particular element with the largest odd order, not a subgroup with the largest odd order. Is there some relation between the two?

Comment: In any case this is a difficult problem that does not have a straightforward answer.

Comment: @coxehj4142, the construction in the comments yields a cyclic subgroup of $A_n$ of maximal odd size, and any element $\sigma$ of your criterion must generate a cyclic subgroup of that size. In any case, I agree with Derek that there is no straightforward answer.

Comment: @David Oh, I've got the idea. That's true if the construction yields a maximum odd-sized cyclic subgroup, but I still don't understand why the construction yields a "maximum"(or maximal) sized subgroup.